# agGroupCellRenderer - example not working, not sure how row groups are established

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I tried implementing the agGroupCellRenderer here (last example on the page): https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

Has anyone been able to get it to work? I copied the code and I do not have any errors, but no table shows up. I did have to remove the import statement for ag-grid-enterprise and the rowGroup attribute in the last three headers as I do not have the Enterprise version, as well as remove the padding styling as I had gotten an error that it was unsupported.

In the example, I also am not clear on how the rowGroups are established. For reference, I am working in Angular 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did have to remove the import statement for ag-grid-enterprise and
>   the rowGroup attribute in the last three headers as I do not have the
>   Enterprise version

Row grouping is an enterprise feature.

It is a bit unclear. If you look [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-features/), or at the menu on the left side of their site, anything with that red (e) symbol is enterprise only.

You can use the ag-grid-enterprise code for evaluation purposes if you like. Your code will probably just work if you have ag-grid-enterprise available and import it.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if they only used free features for an example on the CellRenderer page as CellRenderer is supposed to be free.

Comment: They should definitely mark each individual example as "enterprise only" when they use enterprise features in it. You can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if you want to.

Comment: Can you answer this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410876/how-to-use-tree-data-in-ag-grid-v28